# Tool to display statistic whatever GitHub project is maintained

Tags: statistics, github

I am looking for tool that would display statistics about project health - how quickly maintainers reply to issues and pull requests, how long issues and pull requests are staying open.

Also, it would be useful to see long-term trends - is it regularly maintained? Or are maintainer(s) appearing only sometimes and disappear for months? In addition it would be nice to see "quick action hints" - like "issue #12 is open since 156 BC", "pull request #115 is without comment from maintainer since its opening 10 million years ago".

It may be a web app or desktop program for either Windows 7 or Linux.

I am pretty sure that I encountered project that would display this type of statistics but now I am unable to find it.

I am aware of [Pulse](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse) but it is capable of displaying only short-term statistics (up to one month) and I am interested into long-term info, including trends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is maintained

Well, I found it and it is called "Is it maintained?".

http://isitmaintained.com/

[image]

There is also http://issuestats.com but as author decided to run it on free/really cheap hosting "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments." frequently appears and data is highly outdated.